# Javascript if value is 8,11,18 change "a" to "an"

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

I have a field that reads your lawn takes a ___ hour shower. It is calculated by the square footage input. When the value of this field equals 8,11,or 18. I would like it to read "an ____ hour shower." How would this be made possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/on6c360o/

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var astored = a.getAttribute("data-in");
var g = document.getElementById("g");
setInterval(function() {
  if (a == document.activeElement) {
    var temp = a.value;
    if (astored != temp) {
      astored = temp;
      a.setAttribute("data-in", temp);
      calculate();
    }
  }
}, 10);

function calculate() {
  b.innerHTML = a.value * .62;
  g.innerHTML = Math.round(a.value * .0103);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile" style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Lawn Square Footage</h2>
  <input id="a" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="height: 250px; margin-top: 10px; width: 75%; text-align: center; font-size: 100px;" type="text" data-in="" />
  <h2>Water Usage</h2>
  <h2 id="b">___</h2>
  <h2>Gallons per day</h2>

  <h2>Your lawn takes <span id="g">___</span> hour showers</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to say if hours is 8, 11, or 18 then display `an` else display `a`.

```
var hours = Math.round(a.value * .0103);
g.innerHTML = (hours === 8 || hours === 11 || hours === 18 ? 'an' : 'a') + ' ' + hours;
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/bmec3tad/

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an if check when changing the HTML contents like so:

```
function calculate() {
    b.innerHTML = a.value * .62;

    var gVal = Math.round(a.value * .0103);
    g.innerHTML = gVal + ([8, 11, 18].indexOf(gVal) == -1 ? "a" : "an");
}
```